# why the keyboard listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my code,i want to move the picture(pic1) with the four arrow keyboards,draw some lines as background areas,and the pic move 1s a time,but i meet a problem that i can't move the pic1,who can tell me why it's doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("painting");
    //canvas.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
    var context2D = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var pic = new Image();
    var pic1=new Image();
    var X=0,Y=200;
    var X1=200,Y1=200;
    pic.src = "music.jpg";
    pic1.src = "qingwa.jpg";

    function drawline()
    {
    context2D.moveTo(0,100);
    context2D.lineTo(35,100);
    context2D.lineTo(35,60);
    context2D.lineTo(85,60);
    context2D.lineTo(85,100);
    context2D.lineTo(155,100);
    context2D.lineTo(155,60);
    context2D.lineTo(205,60);
    context2D.lineTo(205,100);
    context2D.lineTo(275,100);
    context2D.lineTo(275,60);
    context2D.lineTo(325,60);
    context2D.lineTo(325,100);
    context2D.lineTo(395,100);
    context2D.lineTo(395,60);
    context2D.lineTo(445,60);
    context2D.lineTo(445,100);
    context2D.lineTo(515,100);
    context2D.lineTo(515,60);
    context2D.lineTo(565,60);
    context2D.lineTo(565,100);
    context2D.lineTo(600,100);


    context2D.stroke();
    }
    function doKeyDown(e)
    {
        switch (e.keyCode)
        {
        // the up key
            case 38:
            Y1 = Y1 - 10;
            break;
        //the down key
            case 40:
            Y1 = Y1 + 10;
            break;

        //the left key
            case 37:
            X1 = X1 - 10;
            break;

        //the right key
            case 39:
            X1 = X1 + 10;
            break;

        }
    }

    function drawfrogger()
    {

        context2D.drawImage(pic1,X1,Y1);
    }
    function draw()
    {

        context2D.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
        context2D.save();
        context2D.drawImage(pic,X,Y);
        drawfrogger();
        drawline();
        context2D.restore(); //绘制结束以后，恢复画笔状态
        if(X>600)
            X = 0;
        X = X + 100;

    }


    setInterval(draw, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Added a working JSFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only elements that can receive focus such as form inputs will generate key events. You have two options:

- Add a `tabindex` attribute to your `<canvas>` element to allow it to receive focus. A value of `0` will place the element in the default tab order (i.e. HTML source order). [Here is article with some more detail](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex).
- Handle key events on `document` instead. This has the disadvantage of capturing key events that originate anywhere in the document, not just the `<canvas>` element you're interested in.

Comment: hi,can you give me the code as your explained above,thanks a lot^^

Comment: hi,here is my another question.How can i post only text in the stackoverflow.i have done that just now but it says i don't meet the format

Answer (score -2):

Change the keydown to:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    doKeyDown(e);
});
```

@jbabey - this works: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/cjRVn/3/

Comment: hi,here is my another question.How can i post only text in the stackoverflow.i have done that just now but it says i don't meet the format